# How do I restore the desktop tile?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, start-screen

I'm using Windows 8 and have managed to lose the Desktop tile.

How do I put it back?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. From the Start screen <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will take you to Desktop.
2. To get its tile back on Start you can do the following:

   1. Whilst on the Start screen type `Desktop`. The screen will change and two items will appear.
   2. Right click on **Desktop**, do not click on Remote Desktop; at the bottom of the screen, a  bar appears where you can select **Pin to Start**, thus putting its tile (back) on the Start Screen.

— [Source](http://www.forumswindows8.com/installation-setup/desktop-tile-has-disappeared-6319.htm)

Comment: @TomWijsman What I do is move the desktop tile to the upper left position, then just hit enter key when the start screen loads, and it loads the desktop, about as easy as it gets without hacking.

Comment: The answer by Graham Wager solved this issue for me, but the above did not help, so keep reading, dear visitors, keep reading.

Answer (score 23):

From the Start Screen, type `Desktop` and you'll find it again.
You can right-click it in the search results and click `Pin to Start` to bring it back permanently.

[image: Search for Desktop]

[image: Pin to Start]

Answer (score 5):

In certain circumstances, the Desktop tile can disappear *without being removed by the user*. The other solutions to this question do not work, as **the Desktop entry disappears completely from both search and the All Apps screens**.

A further symptom of this scenario is that **the Store tile will also disappear**.

This is due to a corrupted or replaced system file. In this case:

- open a Command Prompt as an Administrator:

  - press <kbd>Windows</kbd>
  - type `cmd`
  - press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>to launch as an Administrator
  - if prompted, select Yes to confirm running as an Adminsitrator
- type `sfc /scannow` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

SFC will then scan your system files and replace the problem file. The Desktop and Store tiles should then become available.

**Sidenote:**

If it fails to replace the files, you may have to perform the scan at next boot by using `sfc /scanboot` then rebooting the machine. Once completed use `sfc /revert` to return the tool to normal operation, or it'll scan on every future reboot.

Comment: Both of these happened to me on the same computer, about a month apart.

Answer (score 3):

In the Modern UI, search for `Desktop`, right-click on the result and then click 'Pin to start'

Answer (score 2):

You can type `Desktop` on the Start Screen and right-click on the Desktop icon that appears and select `Pin to start`

You can use the old school shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to go to your desktop

You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go to your desktop
I have not tried this one in windows 8 but I guess it should work -> <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> minimizes all windows and shows your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases what happen is that you delete the `Desktop.lnk` file located in `C:\Users\All Users\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` or from here: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

In that particular case you need to add the shortcut link file back, I got it from [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2246049/Start%20Screen%20Icon%20Restore.zip)  thanks to this discussion [Lost "Desktop" shortcut/tile in Metro UI](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/4703-lost-desktop-shortcut-tile-metro-ui-2.html) at www.eightforums.com

Answer (score 0):

Follow these simple steps to fix the problem:

1. Press "Win+R" keys together to open RUN dialog box. Now copy following string in text box and press Enter:
   **%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs**
   It'll open "Programs" folder containing various shortcuts which are shown at Start Screen or "All Apps" page.
2. Now download Desktop tile shortcut using following **[Link](http://media.askvg.com/downloads/2013/01/Desktop-Tile-for-Windows-8-Start-Screen.zip)** :   Its a ZIP file, extract it and you'll find a file "Desktop" in the extracted folder.
3. Copy "Desktop" file from the extracted folder and paste it in the "Programs" folder which you opened using step 1.
4. That's it. As soon as you copy the shortcut, Desktop tile will be re-added automatically to Start Screen. If you still don't see the tile, you can re-pin it using "All Apps" page. Now it'll appear on that page.

[Source](http://www.askvg.com/fix-desktop-tile-missing-from-windows-8-start-screen-cant-add-from-all-apps-page/)